# anaconda/python 3.6/MacOS 10: gdal unexpectedly stopped working (ImportError)

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, gdal

I have python 3.6.3 running with anaconda 1.8.7/spyder 3.3.1
my script starts with:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal
```

The script was working fine 2 days ago!!! but when I ran it today, I got this error:

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('/Users/planchon/Dropbox/Documents/Python_scripts/Fortuna/lire_points_dans-images.py', wdir='/Users/planchon/Dropbox/Documents/Python_scripts/Fortuna')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-9738155f2c83>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/planchon/Dropbox/Documents/Python_scripts/Fortuna/lire_points_dans-images.py', wdir='/Users/planchon/Dropbox/Documents/Python_scripts/Fortuna')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/planchon/Dropbox/Documents/Python_scripts/Fortuna/lire_points_dans-images.py", line 30, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.71.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Again, this does not looks like an installation problem since the script was working 2 days ago. I wonder what can have been broken in 2 days.

What I have tried so far:

```
$ conda update -n base conda
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

but this did not fix the problem:

```
$ gdalinfo --version
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.71.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/bin/gdalinfo
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

solved by uninstalling and reinstalling gdal

```
conda uninstall gdal
conda install gdal
```